# Extracting intersection between two javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have an array of items like so:  `["Steel", "in", "America", "Iron"]` and another array: `["Steel", "Iron", "Copper"]` that I would like compare array the first array to.

I would like to return an array of items that represent a match between the two arrays, in this case, `["Steel", "Iron"]`

What is the best method to accomplish this task?

Comment: Isn't this same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: thanks, yes, that is it.

Comment: @MikeVelazco: That's the opposite of his desired result, though there are many, many duplicates of this question that one can easily find if one takes just a minute to search.